# Capturing groups and greediness in Python

Tags: python, regex

Recently I have been playing around with regex expressions in Python and encountered a problem with `r"(\w{3})+"` and with its non-greedy equivalent `r"(\w{3})+?"`.
Please let's take a look at the following example:

```
S = "abcdefghi"  # string used for all the cases below
```

**1. Greedy search**

```
m = re.search(r"(\w{3})+", S)
print m.group()   # abcdefghi
print m.groups()  # ('ghi',)
```

`m.group` is exactly as I expected - just whole match.

Regarding `m.groups` please confirm: `ghi` is printed because it has overwritten previous captured groups of `def` and `abc`, am I right? If yes, then can I capture all overwritten groups as well? Of course, for this particular string I could just write `m = re.search(r"(\w{3})(\w{3})(\w{3})", S)` but I am looking for a more general way to capture groups not knowing how many of them I can expect, thus metacharacter `+`.

**2. Non-greedy search**

```
m = re.search(r"(\w{3})+?", S)
print m.group()  # abc
print m.groups() # ('abc',)
```

Now we are not greedy so only `abc` was found - exactly as I expected.

Regarding `m.groups()`, the engine stopped when it found `abc` so I understand that this is the only found group here.

**3. Greedy findall**

```
print re.findall(r"(\w{3})+", S) # ['ghi']
```

Now I am truly perplexed, I always thought that function `re.findall` finds all substrings where the RE matches and returns them as a list. Here, we have only one match  `abcdefghi` (according to common sense and bullet **1**), so I expected to have a list containing this one item. Why only `ghi` was returned?

**4. Non-greedy findall**

```
print re.findall(r"(\w{3})+?", S)  # ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Here, in turn, I expected to have `abc` only, but maybe having bullet **3** explained will help me understand this as well. Maybe this is even the answer for my question from bullet **1** (about capturing overwritten groups), but I would really like to understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about the greedy/non-greedy behavior in the context of your regex (`r"(\w{3})+"`) versus a regex where the repeating pattern was not at the end: (`r"(\w{3})+\w"`)

It's important because the default behavior of regex matching is:

1. The entire regex must match
2. Starting as early in the target string as possible
3. Matching as much of the target string as possible (greedy)

If you have a "repeat" operator - either `*` or `+` - in your regex, then the default behavior is for that to match as *much* as it can, *so long as the rest of the regex is satisfied.*

When the repeat operator is at the end of the pattern, there is no *rest of the regex*, so the behavior becomes match as much as it can.

If you have a repeat operator with a non-greedy qualifier - `*?` or `+?` - in your regex, then the behavior is to match as *little* as it can, *so long as the rest of the regex is satisfied.*

When the repeat-nongreedy operator is at the end of the pattern, there is no *rest of the regex*, so the behavior becomes match as little as it can.

All that is in *just one match*. You are mixing `re.findall()` in as well, which will then repeat the match, if possible.

The first time you run `re.findall`, with `r"(\w{3})+"` you are using a greedy match at the end of the pattern. Thus, it will try to apply that last block as **many** times as possible in a *single match*. You have the case where, like the call to `re.search`, the single match consumes the entire string. As part of consuming the entire string, the w3 block gets repeated, and the group buffer is overwritten several times.

The second time you run `re.findall`, with `r"(\w{3})+?"` you are using a non-greedy match at the end of the pattern. Thus, it will try to apply that last block as **few** times as possible in a *single match*. Since the operator is `+`, that would be 1. Now you have a case where the match can stop without consuming the entire string. And now, the group buffer only gets filled one time, and not overwritten. Which means that findall can return that result (abc), then loop for a different result (def), then loop for a final result (ghi).

Answer (score 1):

> Regarding `m.groups` please confirm: `ghi` is printed because it has overwritten previous captured groups of `def` and `abc`, am I right?

- Right. Only the last captured text is stored in the group memory buffer.

> can I capture all overwritten groups as well?

- Not with `re`, but with [PyPi regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you can. Its match object has a `captures` method. However, with `re`, you can just match them with `re.findall(r'\w{3}', S)`. However, in this  case, you will match all 3-word character chunks from the string, not just those consecutive ones. With the regex module, you can get all the 3-character consecutive chunks from the beginning of the string with the help of `\G` operator: `regex.findall(r"\G\w{3}", "abcdefghi")` (result: `abc`, `def`, `ghi`).

> Why only `ghi` was returned with `re.findall(r"(\w{3})+", S)`?

- Because there is only one match that is equal to the whole `abcdefghi` string, and Capture group 1 contains just the last three characters. `re.findall` only returns the captured values if capturing groups are defined in the pattern.

Comment: If anything is unclear, you can drop a comment here, and I will update the answer with the pertinent details.

Comment: This question is still relevant and of course I have now given credit to people who such selflessly help others. My delay arises due to the fact that I am trying to figure out as much as I can on my own and not to bother helping people with a lot of questions - these two answers were initially incomprehensible and for my yesterday's knowledge required a lot of investigation. Anyway, it seems that my intentions are construed negatively. I am starting to get familiar with this site and don't really know its customs - if it is not unwelcome to have questions right away then it is great.

Comment: It is a Q&A site. Questions should be about programming: you have a task, you work on it, get stuck with some piece of code, you ask for help since you tried this or that, and it does not work. More at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question  of yours is a type of question that happens from time to time, but you really seem to have trouble with understanding basic things. You can learn a lot at [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info).

Comment: Yeah, I really get it, although it still seems a little bit lazy to keep asking again and again without spending at least an hour thinking over already received hints.

I read *How to ask* and this is why I am trying to show my effort in the topics.

I am aware that these are bacics - nothing surprising since I have been experimenting with regexes for several days thus far. In the near future I am going to read some solid book about Python (and regexes in particular) - *Python Essential Reference* caught my attention.
Wiktor, thanks for your help today, it saved me a lot of time.